# Problems compiling with GLEW

Tags: c++, c++11, sdl-2, clion, glew

PS: I've already tried the answers in this link: 
[Supposedly duplicated :(](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

But I didn't get any results, the same error still shows.

I´m trying to compile some code in c++, im using SDL and GLEW,I was trying to create a simple sprite but doing it I get the next output:

[image: Errors]

This is my source:

```
#include "Sprite.h"

Sprite::Sprite() {
    _vboID =0;
}

Sprite::~Sprite() {
    if(_vboID != 0){
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &_vboID);
    }
}

void Sprite::init(float x, float y, float width, float height) {
    x=_x;
    y=_y;
    width=_width;
    height=_height;

    if(_vboID==0){
        glGenBuffers(1,&_vboID);
    }

    float vertexData[12];

    vertexData [0] = x + width;
    vertexData [1] = y + height;

    vertexData [2] = x;
    vertexData [3] = y + height;

    vertexData [4] = x;
    vertexData [5] = y;

    //Second triangle
    vertexData [6] = x;
    vertexData [7] = y;

    vertexData [8] = x + width;
    vertexData [9] = y;

    vertexData [10] = x + width;
    vertexData [11] = y + height;

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vboID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexData), vertexData,     GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

void Sprite::draw() {
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vboID);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

I have all my labraries added, but i have this output.

Comment: Those are linker errors. Usually they mean you neglected to specify a library your code needs to the linker. If you wrote the makefile, you should add it to the question. If it was generated by the IDE, you'll need to find the library configuration panel and add the missing library.

Comment: Are you able to execute any other Glew functions other than the ones in your sprite class?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/2668dad9906dc4e027f339e27a09ee4d  glDrawArrays(); does not make any error

Comment: Do you mean the CMakeLists.txt? https://gyazo.com/668cdf08d73de54f0b4b8793795c56d6

Comment: https://github.com/SupineDread/VideoGameTraining this is my source

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`.  Even more importantly, you don't show your compile and link commands, and they are probably crucial to solving the problem.  Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of the Makefile (or equivalent) that can reproduce this.

Comment: I hace my main funtion and all my #include in the main.cpp, sorry about images. My question was marked as duplicated, maybe otherbusers with my problem can find the answer y the "original". I dont use compile commands i was using Clion, i changed my project to visual studio and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})

and in the target_link_libraries( ... ${GLEW_LIBRARIES} ... )
```

This will most likely fix your problem, but you should dive more deeply into cmake and write a cleaner CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/a3c2d848246965e652ad00cf637f149a testing the CMakeLists i have this output.  I see _GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR GLEW_LIBRARY_ in my FindGLEW.cmake file, i dont know where is missing _GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR GLEW_LIBRARY_

Comment: It seems, like your cmake is not aware of your glew installation. Can you try adding -DGLEW_DIR=<parth_to_glew> to you cmake call?

Comment: I changed all my project to visual studio and it worked, with the same library versions and the same #include. But thanks you Wero so helpful